# Rate limited issue when crawling tweets using Twittr package

Tags: r, twitter

I'm scraping some tweets using the twittR package. It all works fine, but when I want to scrape a significant amount of tweets I get the following message:

```
[1] "Rate limited .... blocking for a minute and retrying up to 119 times ..."
```

From reading [(https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters)] I understand there's a maximum of requests that can be scraped. What I do not understand however is that sometimes I already hit the wall when I crawl 20 tweets and sometimes I can get up to 260 before it's limited.

Any thoughts on what the rate of tweets you can gather per time span is?

Answer (score 0):

Rate Limits, and the way they function works differently from API call to API call, What call are you making specificaly? If you are just interested in gathering Tweets related to a subject, I'd suggest using the streaming API (streamR) as it requires only 1 API Call and allows you to stream for an indefinite amount of time.